# How to use correctly 只要?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I want to ask if this sentence is acceptable:

> 只要我还头疼，就不能去上课。

As I only saw sentences with 只要 in which the condition brings about a result (poisitive) but here the result is negative. Is it a correct sentence?

Comment: previously discussed: esp. see comments at http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17400/what-is-the-difference-between-%e5%8f%aa%e8%a6%81-and-%e5%a6%82%e6%9e%9c , 只要 ≠ only if, 只有 ＝ only if （discussed there)

Comment: Said sentence is okay but not colloquial.

Comment: cf. ＂汉语８００虚词用法词典＂只要［连］［usu. used correlatively with 就，便 or 总］if only; as long as,provided 表示必要的条件。常用在前一个分句里，后一个分句常用＂就、便、总＂等呼应。（１）现在只要你有钱，就能买到自己需要的东西。（２）只要你肯努力，就一定能实现自己当翻译的理想。（３）你只要把这件事跟他说说，他就一定会帮你想办法。（４）我只要喝了咖啡，就一定睡不着觉（５）只要你来，我一定陪你好好儿玩儿几天。（６）这是我的手机号，有什么事你只要给我打个电话，我一定努力去办。（７）你需要什么，只要给他们打个电话，他们就给你送到家去了。（８）这一年我按照老师的要求去做，只要是学过的课文，我便差不多都能背下来。（９）你只要求他，他总是非常热心地帮助你。（１０）我需要什么，只要跟爸爸妈妈提出，他们总是千方百计地满足我的要求。●［比较］一。。。就。。。。只要。。。就。。。＂只要。。。就。。。＂连接的是条件复句，＂一。。。就。。。＂连接的是紧缩句。＂只要＂后面说的是基本的条件、起码的条件，＂就＂表示结果。＂一。。。就。。。＂表示假设，当然＂假设＂也包含假设的条件。因为假设的条件也是条件，所以二者有时可以替换。但它们适用的语境是不同的：＂只要。。。就。。。＂多表示未然，而＂一。。。就。。。＂既可以表示未然，也可以表示已然。

Comment: ＂只要＂可以用在主语前，而＂一＂不能用在主语前。（１）我一／只要喝酒就脸红。（２）开车很容易，一／只要学就会。（３）我一／只要看见他就心跳得厉害。（４）我一／＊只要下课就去医院。（５）他一／＊只要拿到签证就走了。（６）这东西只要／＊一有钱就能买到。（７）这个大夫可神了，他只要／＊一一看就知道你是什么病。（８）只要／＊一你去大家就高兴。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is acceptable.

For example,

只要有人在说话，就不要插嘴。
As long as someone is talking, do not intervene.

只要下雨，我们就不去了。
As long as it rains, we will not go.

只要客户不满意，我们就不会停止服务。
If customers are not satisfied, we will not stop the service.

Answer (score 1):

It's acceptable.I think that you express it this way "只要我头还疼，就没（办）法去上课。"would be better.It could be less stiff.It sounds like that you are forced not to go to school.

Answer (score 1):

只要refer to sufficient condition

只要A，就B：if A then B

it has nothing to do with positive or negative conditions