# Which 相呼应 should I use in 只要?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

只要 means "only if ~" or "as long as ~", and is usually used with 相呼应, such as 就 or 便 in the main clause. At least it is different from 只有, which is used with 才 or 方. But I don't understand which 相呼应 to use for 只要.

So my questions are:

- Are there any other 相呼应 for 只要 other than 就 and 便?
- How should I choose which 相呼应 to use?

Comment: 只要 and 相呼应 are not usually used together, actually, '相呼应' is a very literary term . It is rarely used colloquially. However, "互相呼应" is more commonly used

Comment: I think he means that "就" and "要" are the two "相呼应"s for "只要".

Comment: @fefe Yes that is correct. (就 and 便). Feel free to edit it if it is confusing.

Comment: I thought that is "corresponding conjunctions" ( 相应连词)

Comment: only if (=只有）≠ as long as (只要）see https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17400/what-is-the-difference-between-%e5%8f%aa%e8%a6%81-and-%e5%a6%82%e6%9e%9c

Comment: There doesn't need to be any set `相呼應`, as long as you've expressed that something (1) will naturally follow, (2) must happen, or (3) could happen in your following phrase. E.g. 「衹要有信心，困難**必**戰勝。」, 「衹要你推薦的，我**都**會考慮。」, 「衹要功夫深，鐵杆[unnecessary, but can add **可/會** here]磨成針。」.

Answer (score 1):

只要 indicates a **sufficient condition**, i.e. "只要A就B" means "A => B", "The fact A guarantees the fact B". 就 or 便 usually gives a sense that something is simpler than one expects, so such adverbs match with 只要.

> 只要你努力，你就会成功。
>
> You will (simply) succeed as long as you work hard.

只有 indicates a **necessary condition**, i.e. "只有A才B" means "A <= B",
"Condition A is mandatory for B to be present". 方 or 才 usually gives a sense that something is more difficult than expected, or some scenario requires more conditions than expected to achieve, so these adverbs match with 只有.

> 你只有努力，才会成功。
>
> You can only succeed if you work hard.

In other usages of 就 and 才, they play similar roles, i.e. giving optimistic/pessimistic senses.

> 我老公昨天三点就回来了。
>
> It was only 3 p.m. that my husband came home yesterday. (I didn't expect him to come home so early, but he did).

> 我老公昨天九点才回来。
>
> It was not until 9 p.m. that my husband came home yesterday. (I expected him to come home earlier, but he just kept me waiting).

In English it doesn't require an adverb to complete a sentence with a conditional clause; but in Chinese, without an appropriate adverb like 才 or 就, the sentence will sound incomplete. Since these words are required to form a sentense, your grammar book may suggest they are **conjunctions/连词**, but I think in fact they are **adverbs/副词**.

Among them, 才 and 就 are more common in everyday use, while 便 and 方 may sound too formal. Other possibilities are rare as far as I can think of. I would suggest that you only memorize these two patterns: "只要……就……" and "只有……才……", for these two appear in our primary school textbooks as well.

Answer (score 0):

Question is somewhat unclear. 只要 。。。。就/便 If ..... then (this is a [condition ... result] sentence: If condition = true, then RESULT)

只要 你不再调皮，我 就 给你买冰淇淋。
只要 我考试考满分， 我爸妈便带我去旅游。

我只要吃一个冰淇淋。I just want an ice cream. 只要 ≠ if, only if